# How to re-order a dataframe based on the first non-zero value of specific rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of sales and costs (+other items) of stores opened in different dates, with the columns being months. I want to reorder the dataframe based on the first month where each store's Sales value is non-zero so that the columns go from 1st month of Sales since opening, 2nd month since opening... This is so that I can compare 1st month performance for each store. The dataframe is something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[Store 1, Sales, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0],
                   [Store 1, Costs, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 7.0, 0.0],
                   [Store 2, Sales, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0]
                  ]
                  , columns=['Jan-19', 'Feb-19', 'Mar-19', 'Apr-19', 'May-19', 'June-19', 'Jul-19', 'Aug-19'])

I want to re-order the columns so that they are re-ordered based on the first non-zero value in Sales for each store:

               A    B     C     D     E     F     G     H
Store 1 Sales 3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   
Store 1 Costs 0.0   3.0   1.0   1.0   3.0   7.0  0.0    
Store 2 Sales 15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0
```

I have tried the following to iterate over each row and find the first non zero value:

```
# define a function to find the first non-zero value in a row
def first_non_zero(row):
    for val in row:
        if val != 0:
            return val
    return 0

# apply the function to each row of the DataFrame
df['first_non_zero'] = df.apply(first_non_zero, axis=1)
```

I am more unsure about how to go about re-ordering the whole dataframe based on each store's values. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you fix your example? It's currently invalid

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first two columns are a MultiIndex, you could use a custom [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html):

```
out = (df
   .groupby(level=0, group_keys=False)
   .apply(lambda g: g.loc[:, (m:=g.ne(0).cummax().any())]
                     .set_axis(range(m.sum()), axis=1))
)
```

Output:

```
                  0     1     2     3    4    5
store                                          
Store 1 Sales   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0  7.0  8.0
        Costs   0.0   3.0   1.0   1.0  7.0  0.0
Store 2 Sales  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  NaN  NaN
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Store 1', 'Sales', 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0],
                   ['Store 1', 'Costs', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 7.0, 0.0],
                   ['Store 2', 'Sales', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0]
                  ], columns=['store', None, 'Jan-19', 'Feb-19', 'Mar-19', 'Apr-19', 'May-19', 'June-19', 'Jul-19', 'Aug-19']
                 ).set_index(['store', None])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['Store 1', 'Sales', 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0],
                   ['Store 1', 'Costs', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 7.0, 0.0],
                   ['Store 2', 'Sales', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0]
                  ], columns=['store', None, 'Jan-19', 'Feb-19', 'Mar-19', 'Apr-19', 'May-19', 'June-19', 'Jul-19', 'Aug-19']
                 ).set_index(['store', None])

"""print(df)
           Jan-19  Feb-19  Mar-19  Apr-19  May-19  June-19  Jul-19  Aug-19
store                                                                         
Store 1 Sales     0.0     0.0     3.0     4.0     5.0      6.0     7.0     8.0
        Costs     0.0     0.0     0.0     3.0     1.0      1.0     7.0     0.0
Store 2 Sales     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0    15.0     16.0    17.0    18.0
"""   
"""
np.logical_or.reduce(..., axis=0):

Performs a logical OR operation across all rows within each column.

Reduces the boolean DataFrame to a single boolean array.

Efficiently identifies columns in a DataFrame that contain at least one non-zero value.

Returns a boolean array representing each column, where True indicates a column 
with non-zero values and False indicates all zeros.

df.ne(0) creates a boolean DataFrame indicating which elements 
are not equal to zero (True for non-zero values).

df.ne(0).cummax(axis=0) essentially creates a boolean array where:

True marks a column that has at least one non-zero value.

False marks a column that contains all zeros.
"""      
non_zero_cols = np.logical_or.reduce(df.ne(0).cummax(axis=0),axis=0)
"""print(non_zero_cols)        
[False False  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 """
#Get column names based on True values
selected_cols = df.columns[non_zero_cols]
"""
print(selected_cols)
Index(['Mar-19', 'Apr-19', 'May-19', 'June-19', 'Jul-19', 'Aug-19'], dtype='object')
"""

res = df[selected_cols].set_axis(np.arange(len(selected_cols)), axis=1)

"""print(res)
                 0    1     2     3     4     5
store                                          
Store 1 Sales  3.0  4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0
        Costs  0.0  3.0   1.0   1.0   7.0   0.0
Store 2 Sales  0.0  0.0  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0"""
```

Method 2 :

```
def calculate_indices(df):

    num_columns = len(df.columns)
    start_index = num_columns - 6
    end_index = num_columns
    return start_index, end_index

start_index, end_index = calculate_indices(df)

# Reshape the DataFrame and rename columns
out = (df.stack()
   .unstack(fill_value=0) #ensures that missing values (NaNs) are replaced with 0s.
   #.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
   .iloc[:, start_index:end_index]
   .set_axis([str(i) for i in range(6)], axis=1)
)

print(out)
"""                0    1     2     3     4     5
store                                          
Store 1 Costs  0.0  3.0   1.0   1.0   7.0   0.0
        Sales  3.0  4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0
Store 2 Sales  0.0  0.0  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0
"""
```

Method 3 :

```
out = (df.stack()  # Stack without filtering 0s
         .unstack(fill_value=0)  # Fill with 0s instead of NaNs
         #.dropna(axis=1, how='all')  # Drop columns with all 0s
         .iloc[:, -6:] #selects the last 6 columns of the DataFrame.
         .set_axis([str(i) for i in range(6)], axis=1)  # Start column names from 0
        )
print(out)
                 0    1     2     3     4     5
store                                          
Store 1 Costs  0.0  3.0   1.0   1.0   7.0   0.0
        Sales  3.0  4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0
Store 2 Sales  0.0  0.0  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0
```